# Modifying katharsis json response

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, katharsis

I am using katharsis with spring boot.
I want to change the 'id' key in json response with my table PK column name, following is the katharsis response

```
    {
     "type": "table-name",
     "id": "A",
     "attributes": {
     "description": "AAA"
    },
    "relationships": {

     },
     "links": {
       "self": "http://localhost/table-name/A"
     }
    }
```

I want to change the above "id": "A" with "coulmnName":"A".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer on katharsis github repository

https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-core/issues/203

Comment: Hi, Seems the link not existing. Do you have any idea how to do this? I also want remove "self": "http://localhost/table-name/A".  Thanks.